# WCF UserNameTransport Error in AWS environment- An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, wcf, ssl, amazon-ec2

I have a WCF application which should work over SSL. Configured SSL using Self signed certificate in my local machine and it is working fine.

I am getting following error when I moved the application to AWS EC2 instance.

Exception:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner  FaultException for the code and detail.

Exception, after checking tracelog.svclog:

> Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. this might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties. this can occur if the service is configured for a security and the client is not using security.

Binding used for this application,

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="httpBasic" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" >
        </security>
        <textMessageEncoding  messageVersion="Soap11"/>  
        <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
              keepAliveEnabled="false" transferMode="Streamed"/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

AWS environment:

EC2 instance is windows 10 machine which is behind the classic load balancer and the load balancer is SSL configured using Route 53.

EC2 instance is not a graphical User interface. It has only access to DOS command prompt.

Configured SSL in EC2 instance IIS by updating the config file (`%WinDir%\System32\Inetsrv\Config\applicationHost.config`) as below:

```
<site
   <bindings>
      <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:443:" />
   </bindings>
</site>
```

Tried following changes so far, bindings are same both the ends.

```
includeTimestamp - false
enableUnsecuredResponse- true
maxClockSkew-10:00:00
```

After changing these things in bindings security, I am not seeing the "unsecured or incorrectly secured fault" error. but,username is not receiving in service end.

I have verified this by logging the user name.

Certificate is not configured in EC2 instance IIS since certificate is already configured in load balancer. Do we need IIS certificate to process the incoming request messages?

Please provide your suggestions to receive the security credentials(username and password)correctly at the service end.

Thank you

Comment: I am not familiar with load balancer, it is a good idea that try to set up the certificate in server end since the server use the httpstransport binding element.

Comment: Can you log it on the server side using the SercurityAudit node in the service behavior in web config? Most likely the load balancer is still passing the HTTPS to IIS so you likely have to have https in IIS with a private key cert.

Comment: Thank you Abarahim. We are planning to add certificate.

Comment: Thank you Popo. After adding SecurityAudit element, I am getting "Message authentication succeeded." in local machine. but, no messages logged in ec2 instance server.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the certificate to the EC2 instance IIS, the application is able to extract the credentials.